# How to prove an expectation inequality?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be mutually independent random variables, and for each $X_i$, there is $P(X_i=1)=p$ and $P(X_i=0)=1-p$.

Let $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ be binary random variables defined by 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
Y_1&=X_1,\\
Y_t&=\begin{cases}
1,&\mbox{if $\frac{1}{t}\sum^t_{j=1}X_j\ge p+(1-2p)\frac{1}{t-1}\sum^{t-1}_{i=1}Y_i$}\\
0,&\mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

We'd like to prove that 
\begin{equation}
E(Y_t)=Pr(Y_t=1)\le p, \ \ \ \forall\, t=1,2,\ldots
\end{equation}

Could you please tell me how to prove it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are your thoughts? A proof by induction seems prudent here.

Comment: @Math1000 We tried induction, but we didn't see how it works here.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Could you please send me the link again? Thanks.

Comment: Oops, sorry. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3033998/calculating-the-expectation-of-a-sum-of-dependent-random-variables) recent thread may be useful for you, because it deals with almost the same $Y_i$ (the only difference is that in its definition you have “$\le$”, whereas there is “$>$”; also there $p<0.5$).

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks a lot.